# How to access the oracle stored procedures or functions returning sysrefcursor from crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a stored procedure in below format.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MAPSADMIN"."FORECAST_MAINTENANCE_SCH" (
   inparam VARCHAR2,
   outparam OUT ref cursor)
```

We need to access the ref cursor specifed in the out param in our crystal report.

We are able to view the procedure in the report but we do not know how to map the cursor columns in the report columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on something similar.

My stored Procedure declaration looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EASDEV."TMP_UPDT_LAST_RUN_PROC"
(
   InReportName IN varchar2,
   p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
).................
```

In **Crystal [2011],** using the *Std Rpt Creation Wizard* I selected a native connection to Oracle, specified the user/pw and then browsed into the Oracle db and selected the Stored Procedure. I was prompted for the stored proc's input parameter and then the Wizard displayed the Stored Procedure in the right-pane Selected Tables section.

I cicked Next and the left-pane Available Fields list showed all of the fields that are in the ref cursor that the Stored Procedure returns. I selected the ones that I wanted which put them in the Fields to Display section [right-pane].

I hope this is helpful.
- Bill